# What ionic compound has the lowest boiling point?

Tags: electrochemistry, ions

Defining a molecule as "ionic" when it has a net electronegativity difference greater than 1.7 on Pauling's scale, which ionic compound has the lowest boiling point? And when it evaporates, how do the ions interact with other, cooler molecules? Would evaporated NaCl molecules interact as if they were vaporized Na and Cl that just didn't interact with each other because of the high temperature?

Comment: With regard to vapor phase NaCl, this may be of interest: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/160399/79678. And there are organic ionic salts that are liquid at room temperature, so perhaps their freezing points, or maybe glass-transition temperatures, are relevant?

Comment: Apparently even polymeric chains of NaCl are present at appropriate temperatures: https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article-abstract/104/17/6724/480421/Sodium-chloride-vapor-at-very-high-temperatures?redirectedFrom=fulltext